# Select drive partition table in preseed file automated Debian install

Tags: debian, partition, system-installation, preseed

I am using a preseed file for my Debian installs.  I am using 1TB drives, and I would like to use MS-DOS partition tables.  It is defaulting to GPT.

Is there a way to choose which type of table to use in the preseed file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debconf question `partman-partitioning/default_label` should set the partition table type.

You also need to set the boolean question `partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label` to `true` or partman will not overrite an existing partition table.

So you should put in your pressed file :

```
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label select msdos
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
```